# Flutter how to convert string date to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: flutter

I am fetching data through api issue is date is coming like string

```
2020-11-24T21:26:01.627
```

I simply print it now `print((widget.text['OrderCheckouts'] as Map)['CheckoutDate']);`

I want to print it in dd/MM/yyyy format

i know its dumb question but i am not able to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [Intl DateFormat](https://pub.dev/packages/intl):

```
DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(formattedString));
```